# Eclipse doesn't understand the presence of Maven Dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

So I checked out the MitreID WebApp from https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server and wanted to alter it in different ways.

What stops me from actually doing so is that Eclipse doesn't seem to recognize the Maven dependencies. While trying to reimplement the login component I found out that not only the Spring Security dependency isn't available but everything listet in "Maven Dependencies" is inaccessible.

Building the base project using Maven works fine, changing some settings isn't a problem. But Eclipse lists every class as uncompilable for the various missing dependencies and the classes that I add cannot be compiled during the maven build.

I added the line

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
```

to my .classpath file within eclipse. Before that, "Maven Dependencies" wasn't displayed within Eclipse.

Comment: Do you have M2Eclipse installed?

Comment: Quite possibly the project was imported using the wrong template and thus the project didn't have any kind of maven nature/facets. Hard to say with basically an "it doesn't work".

Comment: Yes, m2eclipse is installed. Other projects can be edited without an issue using the maven dependencies.

Comment: @Gimby: Building the project without adding classes works, but fails as soon as I add my own classes. Eclipse cannot find any of the dependencies although they are included in the "Maven Dependencies" folder which is included in the Eclipse build path. (I am aware that "Eclipse build path" and the maven build path aren't the same entity.)

Comment: What does the `.project` file look like?

Comment: If the project has the correct template, the project icon in the project explorer will have a small M in the top left corner.  If your project does not have the M, right mouse on the project and select Configure!convert to maven.  here is an example link: http://crunchify.com/how-to-convert-existing-java-project-to-maven-in-eclipse/

Comment: @DwB: The tiny blue M is present. I could even use "Run as... Maven build" successfully before adding my own class files.

Comment: I usually just use `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and it works fine in eclipse. If I'm adding dependencies, I need to add it in the `pom.xml` file.